# Повторить функционал маршрутов яндекс карт

Tags: javascript, yandex-geocoding-api, ux

стоит задача повторить функционал построения маршрута как на странице в яндекс картах

https://yandex.ru/maps/11121/almetyevsk/?ll=52.297113%2C54.901383&z=14&mode=routes&rtext=54.911917%2C52.263382~54.894705%2C52.292221&rtt=auto

[image: Скриншот с маршрутом]

Также должна присутствовать возможность перестроения маршрута пользователем с помощью мыши. На странице карт в примерах не нашел ничего подобного

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В примерах есть примеры на маршруты https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_driving и на создание собственных контролов https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_control . Можете видоизменить их так как вам хочется.

И есть пример как добавить панель маршрутов на карту:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/route_panel_control

Comment: Вариант https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/route_panel_control подошел